# Pendulum clock, escapement pallet mounting position

Tags: mechanical-engineering

Im interested in creating a 3d printed pendulum clock, 
all the diagrams and files I can find are mounting the pallet at the top of the escapement wheel which causes more complex design to avoid pendulum rod with the rest of the clock, 
why cant the pallet be mounted downwards from the escapement wheel? is there any particular reason?

Comment: "Avoiding the rest of the clock" isn't really an issue, The traditional layout has the clock gears mounted in a frame, the face outside the front of the frame, the driving weights hanging below the frame, and the escapement and pendulum outside the back. That's a simple and logical layout.

Answer (score 1):

If pallet was to be on the bottom it would tend to fall into the escape gear at the left and right of each tick tack, so it needed to have ballasts balancing it, which adds more inertia than the escape gear can handle.

While when it is positioned on top the connection to pendulum is naturally balanced with lighter assembly.